# Equality in the integration with respect to a measure

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Assume $\mu$ is a probability measure, and the associated distribution function with measure $\mu$ is $F(x)$ given by
$$u((a,b])=F(b)-F(a)$$
Here, the integration of function $g$ with respect to the measure $\mu$ is denoted as $\int g d\mu$. In many references, it said that this integration has the following
$$\int g d\mu = \int g dF.$$
I know that the notation $d\mu$ on left hand side implies the measure. However, since $F$ is not a measure, what is the meaning of $dF$? I am confused why the equality holds. I guess that the equality transfers the integration with respect to measure $\mu$ to Lebesgue Measure, but how can we interpret it?

Comment: $\int g dF$ is defined as $\int d\mu$. In special cases it becomes a Riemann Steiltje's integral.

Answer (score 1):

As a distribution function of a probability measure, $F: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is non-decreasing and hence (to consider the question in a broader context) in particular of bounded variation. Now for reasonable functions $g: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ and $h$ of bounded variation, the term $\int g dh$ is (as said in the comment above) defined as the Lebesgue-Stieltjes integral of $g$ w.r.t. $h$. As I said, $F$ is, by assumption, of bounded variation. If you don't know much about L.-S.-integration, you may should read about this first.